# CRM 2011 and 2013 open in mobile mode on IE 11

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I just got updated to IE 11 and when I log on to CRM 2013 it takes me to the mobile version of the application. Same with 2013.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas on how to fix this other than changing the browser mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick fix around this is to add `/main.aspx` in the end of URL.

eg. your CRM URL would be `http://xyz:5555/orgname` then just append to it `http://xyz:5555/orgname/main.aspx` and you should be able to access CRM normally.

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer 11 isn't currently supported by CRM 2011, you can add the site to the Compatibility View Settings to resolve the issue.

**Update:**

Internet Explorer 11 is supported by CRM 2011 from Update Rollup 17

Internet Explorer 11 is supported by CRM 2013 from Update Rollup 2

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Compatibility List](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3005163)

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Compatibility List](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3005167)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after doing some digging, I was able to locate this which looks like it has a very promising workaround that DOESN'T need to be applied on each indvidual machine, but rather is done at the IIS level via URL rewriting.  http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2013/12/12/stopping-internet-explorer-11-from-showing-the-mobile-express-version-of-dynamics-crm-2011/

Note: this will only work on an onsite deployment - unfortunately there's still not a solid workaround for an online deployment short of what was already pointed out.

Comment: Nice, but only possible for On-Prem.

Comment: true....i suppose for an online deployment you wouldn't really have IIS access.  answer now reflects this.

Answer (score 1):

CU17 on CRM2011 and CU2 on CRM2013 now solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the website that isn't displaying properly.
2. In Internet Explorer (desktop), tap and hold on the bar at the top (or right click).
3. Tap on "Menu bar" so it's highlighted and there is a tick by it. A menu with File, Edit, View, Favourites, Tools and Help should appear.
4. Go to tools and open "Compatibility View Settings". "Add this website" should have the domain of the site you've visited already filled, so click "Add".
5. Close the windows then refresh the website that wasn't displaying properly. It should hopefully now display as it should.